# my QT designer plugin does not find externals

Tags: c++, qt, boost, cmake, qt-designer

I built a QT Designer custom plugin which works just fine..until i add a header which is not in the same library...

if i add this to the MTBFWidget.cpp/.h :

```
#include "KinectHandler.h"
```

the plugin is not found anymore. if i delete it, it works..this tells me that it cannot find any externals. I am really stuck at the moment and i appreciate help in every form.. i think my problem might be my CMakeLists.txt, which tells how to build the dll/lib..here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
    ########### Client Library ###############


    find_package( Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL REQUIRED )
    include( ${QT_USE_FILE} )
    LINK_LIBRARIES( ${QT_LIBRARIES} )

    SET (CLIENT_SOURCES  client.cpp
                         mtbf.cpp
                         pose.cpp
                         MTBFReader.cpp
                         KinectHandler.cpp )

    SET (CLIENT_HEADERS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client.h 
                        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mtbf.h
                        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pose.h
                        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MTBFReader.h
                        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/KinectHandler.h
                        )

    ADD_LIBRARY(client SHARED  ${CLIENT_SOURCES} ${CLIENT_HEADERS} ${CLIENT_MOC_SRC} ${UISrcs})

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(client ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${ODYSSEUS_LIBRARIES})

    ###########################QT Designer Plugin ###################

    set (PLUGIN_MOC_H ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MTBFWidgetPlugin.h 
                      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mtbfwidget.h)

    set (PLUGIN_SRCS MTBFWidgetPlugin.cpp 
                     mtbfwidget.cpp)

    include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                        ${QT_QTDESIGNER_INCLUDE_DIR} )

    QT4_WRAP_CPP( MOCsrc ${PLUGIN_MOC_H} )

    ADD_LIBRARY(mtbf_plugin SHARED  ${MOCsrc}  ${PLUGIN_MOC_H} ${PLUGIN_SRCS} )

    add_dependencies(mtbf_plugin client )

    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mtbf_plugin PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${QT_DEFINITIONS} -DQDESIGNER_EXPORT_WIDGETS -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SHARED")

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mtbf_plugin ${QT_LIBRARIES} client ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${ODYSSEUS_LIBRARIES})

    set( QT_PLUGIN_PATH $ENV{QT_PLUGIN_PATH} )
    if( QT_PLUGIN_PATH )
        get_target_property( TMP_LIBRARY_PATH mtbf_plugin LOCATION )
        add_custom_command( TARGET mtbf_plugin POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ARGS -E copy ${TMP_LIBRARY_PATH} ${QT_PLUGIN_PATH}/designer )
    endif( QT_PLUGIN_PATH )
```

**EDIT :**

Any QT related include works. Every other include outside does not

works :

```
#include "QtGui\qabstractbutton.h"
```

does not work :

```
#include "boost\thread.hpp"
```

The strange thing is, my program can find all those files, it even compiles correctly..

Comment: EDIT : it seems that the problem is, qt designer cannot find boost..because every time i include something with boost it doesnt find it

Answer (score 1):

Finally....i found the solution..if **ANYONE** has this problem :

you need to copy all external dependencies ( in my case boost DLLs ) into the **Qt/X.X.X/bin**
folder

to solve it for me :  C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\boost_system-vc100-mt-1_52.dll needs to exist.

What could also help finding your dependencies : download dependency checker, see which .dll is needed, and drop it to the Qt bin folder.

Comment: You can also use CMake's fixup_bundle scripts to find and copy your dependencies into a CMake install folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check here

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                    ${QT_QTDESIGNER_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

I think you have add boost include folder in this list. And copy this `"KinectHandler.h"`
file to your Project directory /include